# What is the reason for the " 's " in the following context?

Tags: american-english, british-english

You're a friend of **Tom's**, aren't you?

Question: What does the **'s** in **Tom's** stand for?

Comment: You might also be interested in my question about this on ELU: [Why is it usually “friend of **his**”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of **Peter**”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/) But just because *a friend of **Tom / Peter*** is more common than *...of **Tom's / Peter's*** doesn't imply either version is "better" than the other.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't stand for anything: it is simply the possessive clitic exactly as in *Tom's friend.*

There is an unobvious rule in English that though we say

> my friend

and

> Tom's friend

we don't normally say

> *a friend of me

or

> *a friend of Tom.

The idiomatic phrases are

> a friend of mine

and

> a friend of Tom's".

I hesitate to say the other forms are ungrammatical, but they are certainly not natural in current English. I think I can imagine a converation like

> Who is that man over there? I don't know, I thought he was with you. I think he must be a friend of Tom.

Even in that context, "a friend of Tom's" is more likely, but I think "of Tom" is possible.

Comment: I asked about this years ago on ELU citing [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friend%20of%20Peter,friend%20of%20Peter%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20Peter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20Peter%27s%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20Peter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20Peter's%3B%2Cc0) as "evidence" that *it's usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”*. And I don't remember anyone pointing out that my question was based on a false premise...

Comment: ...but seeing what you say here, I just concocted [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friend+of+John+who%2Cfriend+of+John%27s+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20John%20%27s%20who%3B%2Cc0), which certainly backs up your assertion that the "apostrophe-less" form is ***less*** common with *friend of Tom* (personally, I'm happy with both; I don't think I've got any real preference). I guess I messed up that original NGram 'cos I didn't understand how to devise a valid query.

Answer (score 0):

It's another way of saying "You're one of Tom's friends, aren't you?"

The 's is the possessive.